# Collision detection of moving objects

Tags: collision-detection, computational-geometry, recommendation-engine

Say I have several moving objects. I know their shape (which is simple like box, sphere, cylinder) and their position function though out time (which is non-linear). I'd like to detect when and where they collide with another specific moving object (a special object). I was hoping some kind of library existed that detected the point in space and time that two objects would collide but I couldn't find one.

Are you aware of any efficient algorithms to solve this problem or any libraries (in any language) to solve it?

Comment: The collision classes (actually structs) are Open Source in the Monogame Framework. I ripped them out and added them to my game engine.

Comment: Which kind of non - linear position function do you have?

Comment: Parametric functions of polynomials

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of algorithms out there, but they're all object type-specific. The general pattern for linear velocity is, you take the equation for shape/shape distance, parameterize it on time (given the objects' relative position and relative velocity), and solve for a distance of zero.

For instance, if you had two spheres, and the relative position of the second with respect to the first was X0, and the relative velocity of the second with respect to the first was V, and the spheres had radii r1 and r2, you'd solve `D(t) = ||X0 + V*t|| - (r1+r2) = 0`.

For non-linear motion, you basically have X(t) as a function, instead of `X(t) = X0+V*t`. Depending on how complicated that function is, this might be easy, or it might be hard. Assuming it's hard (it probably is), you'd go for an iterative solving method like Newton-Raphson. Luckily, distance formulas tend to be easy to take derivatives of.

The other option for non-linear motion is to discretize it into linear steps. In a way that's just a cheap-n-cheerful iterative method, but given that most approaches to this sort of thing assume linear velocity, it's probably the most straightforward way to apply them.

Of course, I'm cheating by using spheres there. Boxes and cylinders are rather more annoying to find distances for, particularly if they're rotating. I can recommend Ericson's "Real-Time Collision Detection" as the standard book on the topic; it has a number of recipes for various shape pairs, as well as heavy-duty methods for more complicated shapes.